# Deploy spark driver application without spark submit

Tags: java, apache-spark

Let's suppose we have a spark driver program written like this:

```
public class SimpleApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String logFile = "YOUR_SPARK_HOME/README.md"; // Should be some file on your system
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<String> logData = sc.textFile(logFile).cache();

    long numAs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
      public Boolean call(String s) { return s.contains("a"); }
    }).count();

    long numBs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
      public Boolean call(String s) { return s.contains("b"); }
    }).count();

    System.out.println("Lines with a: " + numAs + ", lines with b: " + numBs);
  }
}
```

and I want to run in a yarn cluster, can I avoid using spark-submit and (supposing of course I have access to one cluster node ), by just specifying in the context I want to run on yarn? In other words, is it possible to launch the spark client as a regular java app leveraging yarn?

Comment: If written in Scala, I know you can just use `spark-shell -i file.scala --master yarn-client`. I don't think Java supports that, though

Answer (score 4):

Here is another official way to do it.

**Spark Launcher  - Library for launching Spark applications.**

This library allows applications to launch Spark programmatically. There's only one entry point to the library - the SparkLauncher class.

To launch a Spark application, just instantiate a SparkLauncher and configure the application to run. For example:

```
 import org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher;

   public class MyLauncher {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       Process spark = new SparkLauncher()
         .setAppResource("/my/app.jar")
         .setMainClass("my.spark.app.Main")
         .setMaster("local")
         .setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_MEMORY, "2g")
         .launch();
       spark.waitFor();
     }
   }
```

You can set all the YARN specific config using *setConf* method and set the master to **yarn-client** or *yarn-cluster*

References: 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

From [a Hortonworks blog post](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/28070/starting-spark-jobs-directly-via-yarn-rest-api.html):

**1) Copy Spark assembly jar to HDFS**

Per default the spark assembly jar file is not available in HDFS. For remote access we will need it.

Some standard locations in HDP are:

```
HDP 2.3.2:
    Version: 2.3.2.0-2950
    Spark Jar: /usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.1.2.3.2.0-2950-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950.jar
HDP 2.4.0:
    Version: 2.4.0.0-169
    Spark Jar: /usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.0.2.4.0.0-169-hadoop2.7.1.2.4.0.0-169.jar
```

This is a one time preparation step, for example for HDP 2.4 it would be:

```
sudo su - hdfs
HDP_VERSION=2.4.0.0-169
SPARK_JAR=spark-assembly-1.6.0.2.4.0.0-169-hadoop2.7.1.2.4.0.0-169.jar
hdfs dfs -mkdir "/hdp/apps/${HDP_VERSION}/spark/"
hdfs dfs -put "/usr/hdp/${HDP_VERSION}/spark/lib/$SPARK_JAR" "/hdp/apps/${HDP_VERSION}/spark/spark-hdp-assembly.jar"
```

**2) Upload your spark application jar file to HDFS**

Upload your spark application jar file packaged by sbt to the project folder in HDFS via WebHdfs (maybe use something better than "/tmp"):

```
export APP_FILE=simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar
curl    -X PUT "${WEBHDFS_HOST}:50070/webhdfs/v1/tmp/simple-project?op=MKDIRS"
curl -i -X PUT "${WEBHDFS_HOST}:50070/webhdfs/v1/tmp/simple-project/${APP_FILE}?op=CREATE&overwrite=true"
# take Location header from the response and issue a PUT request
LOCATION="http://..."
curl -i -X PUT -T "target/scala-2.10/${APP_FILE}" "${LOCATION}"
```

**3) Create spark property file and upload to HDFS**

```
spark.yarn.submit.file.replication=3
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=384
spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=384
spark.master=yarn
spark.submit.deployMode=cluster
spark.eventLog.enabled=true
spark.yarn.scheduler.heartbeat.interval-ms=5000
spark.yarn.preserve.staging.files=true
spark.yarn.queue=default
spark.yarn.containerLauncherMaxThreads=25
spark.yarn.max.executor.failures=3
spark.executor.instances=2
spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs\:///spark-history
spark.history.kerberos.enabled=true
spark.history.provider=org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider
spark.history.ui.port=18080
spark.history.fs.logDirectory=hdfs\:///spark-history
spark.executor.memory=2G
spark.executor.cores=2
spark.history.kerberos.keytab=none
spark.history.kerberos.principal=none
```

and upload it via WebHDFS as spark-yarn.properties to your simple-project folder as before

**4) Create a Spark Job json file**

**a) We need to construct the command to start the Spark ApplicationMaster:**

```
java -server -Xmx1024m -Dhdp.version=2.4.0.0-169 \
     -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=/hadoop/yarn/log/rest-api \
     -Dspark.app.name=SimpleProject \
     org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster \
     --class IrisApp --jar __app__.jar \
     --arg '--class' --arg 'SimpleProject' \
     1><LOG_DIR>/AppMaster.stdout 2><LOG_DIR>/AppMaster.stderr
```

It is important to provide the Spark Application Name and the HDP Version. Spark will resolve

**b) We need to set some general environment variables**

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_60/"
SPARK_YARN_MODE=true
HDP_VERSION="2.4.0.0-169"
```

Then we need to tell Spark which files to distribute across all Spark executors. Therefor we need to set 4 variables. One variable is of format "#,#, ...", and the three others contain comma separated timestamps, file sizes and visbility of each file (same order):

```
SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES: "hdfs://<<name-node>>:8020/tmp/simple-project/simple-project.jar#__app__.jar,hdfs://<<name-node>>:8020/hdp/apps/2.4.0.0-169/spark/spark-hdp-assembly.jar#__spark__.jar"
SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_FILE_SIZES: "10588,191724610"
SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_TIME_STAMPS: "1460990579987,1460219553714"
SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_VISIBILITIES: "PUBLIC,PRIVATE"
```

Replace <> with the correct address. File size and timestamp can be retrieved from HDFS vie WebHDFS.

Next, construct the classpath

```
CLASSPATH="{{PWD}}<CPS>__spark__.jar<CPS>{{PWD}}/__app__.jar<CPS>{{PWD}}/__app__.properties<CPS>{{HADOOP_CONF_DIR}}<CPS>/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/lib/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/lib/*<CPS>{{PWD}}/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*<CPS>{{PWD}}/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*<CPS>{{PWD}}/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*<CPS>{{PWD}}/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*<CPS>{{PWD}}/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*<CPS>{{PWD}}/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*<CPS>{{PWD}}/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.6.0.2.4.0.0-169.jar<CPS>/etc/hadoop/conf/secure<CPS>"
```

Notes: - **spark**.jar and **app**.jar are the same as provided in SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES

- Spark will resolve  to `:`

**c) Create the Spark job json file**

The information above will be added to the Spark json file as the command and environment attribute (details see attachment - remove the .txt ending)

The last missing piece are the so called local_resources which describes all files in HDFS necessary for the Spark job: - Spark assembly jar (as in the caching environment variable) - Spark application jar for this project (as in the caching environment variable) - Spark properties file for this project (only for Application Master, no caching necessary)

All three need to be given in a form

```
{
  "key": "__app__.jar", 
  "value": {
    "resource": "hdfs://<<name-node>>:8020/tmp/simple-project/simple-project.jar", 
    "size": 10588, 
    "timestamp": 1460990579987, 
    "type": "FILE", 
    "visibility": "APPLICATION"
  }
},
```

Again, replace <>. Timestamp, hdfs path, size and key need to be the same as for the caching environment variables.

Save it as spark-yarn.json (details see attachment - remove the .txt ending)

**5) Submit the job**

First request an application ID from YARN

```
curl -s -X POST -d '' \
     https://$KNOX_SERVER:8443/gateway/default/resourcemanager/v1/cluster/apps/new-application
# {
#   "application-id": "application_1460195242962_0054",
#   "maximum-resource-capability": {
#     "memory": 8192,
#     "vCores": 3
#   } 
# }
```

Edit the "application-id" in spark-yarn.json and then submit the job:

```
curl -s -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" ${HADOOP_RM}/ws/v1/cluster/apps \
     --data-binary spark-yarn.json 
# HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
# 
# HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
# Cache-Control: no-cache
# Expires: Sun, 10 Apr 2016 13:02:47 GMT
# Date: Sun, 10 Apr 2016 13:02:47 GMT
# Pragma: no-cache
# Expires: Sun, 10 Apr 2016 13:02:47 GMT
# Date: Sun, 10 Apr 2016 13:02:47 GMT
# Pragma: no-cache
# Content-Type: application/json
# Location: http://<<resource-manager>>:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps/application_1460195242962_0054
# Content-Length: 0
# Server: Jetty(6.1.26.hwx)
```

See also a useful python helper by the blog post's author in [this gitlab project](https://github.com/bernhard-42/spark-yarn-rest-api).

Comment: This looks like a lot more work than just using `spark-submit`. The JAR is required to be built anyways.

Comment: @cricket_007 that is the reason spark-submit hides all these complexities and does the work for you

Comment: @cricket_007 I have added an answer where you can utilize the spark-launcher library.

Comment: Hi @RakeshRakshit , it looks like you just copied most of this content from a blog . I've edited your post to give attribution to the author. Plagiarism isn't really welcomed on Stack Overflow, and it's always nice to give credit where credit is due. Thanks for providing this answer nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

See this projects :

https://github.com/cloudera/livy

https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver

Both are easy to use and expose a rest interface to deploy and run spark application.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client`, which provides the API that you want to use. It allows you to define a `SparkConf`, command line arguments and then submits the corresponding job to Yarn using a `run()` method.

I suspect that this is what you want to achieve.

I've found the following [tutorial](https://github.com/mahmoudparsian/data-algorithms-book/blob/master/misc/how-to-submit-spark-job-to-yarn-from-java-code.md) in another question, which gives a brief practical example.

Alternatively, here is another [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20170927060342/http://blog.rocana.com/how-to-submit-spark-jobs-to-yarn-from-java), covering the issue.

And this is the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/Client.scala), for reference, since the API isn't exactly documented.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16140789)

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani thanks for the tip, I have added the essential information, as well as provided addiitonal references, which should serve as a starting point.